# PHP: how to know that all letters in a string are upper case?

Tags: php, string, conditional-statements, uppercase

How to know that all letters in a string are upper case?

Answer (score 21):

You can use [strtoupper](http://php.net/strtoupper) to convert your string to uppercase. You now know that it is uppercase, and you can check if the original string matches it.

ie.

```
$str === strtoupper($str)
```

Answer (score 10):

You could try making a copy of the string, convert the copy to upper case, and compare it to the original string:

```
public function isUpperCase ($string) {
   return $string === strtoupper($str);
}
```

OR, a better version (which is multibyte-safe*) would be:

```
public function mb_isUpperCase ($string) {
   $upper = mb_convert_case( 
      $string, 
      MB_CASE_UPPER, 
      mb_detect_encoding( 
         $string
      )
   );
   return $string === $upper;
}
```

*Note that [mb_detect_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) can fail, and return false. In a production environment you should either provide a list of possible encodings to [mb_detect_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php), or handle the case where [mb_detect_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) fails.

Comment: Only issue I have with the multibyte version is the encoding detection, which is a notoriously difficult thing to do, and will mangle your string if it gets it wrong. +1 for the only real way to do it though.

Comment: Agreed. Added a little comment for that case

Answer (score 4):

```
if(strcmp(strtoupper($str), $str) === 0) {
    echo 'is uppercase';
}
```

Use [`mb_strtoupper`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php) where special character encodings are involved.

Use [`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) for binary-safe string comparison.

Answer (score 4):

ctype_upper() might be a possibility if all the characters are letters, and it's an ascii string.

Answer (score 0):

If its a long string and you don't want to make a copy then walk the string and look at each character's ascii value.  If it is less than 97 you know it is all uppercase.